# Using Knockout.js autocomplete, how can I bind to the right property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, autocomplete

Ok, I am working on a program that has an autocomplete function and am having trouble binding to the property I want. The *data* object is an array of objects that have properties such as UserName and FullName. So if data[0].UserName is 'John.Doe' then data[0].FullName would be 
'John Doe'. When debugging, I can see that the data object has all of the correct values. This is the mapping object:

```
var EmployeeViewModel = function (data) {
    this.Email = ko.observable();
    this.FullName = ko.observable();
    this.$type = 'EmployeeViewModel ';
};

var AdSearchResultsViewModel = function (data) {
    this.Email = ko.observable();
    this.FullName = ko.observable();
    this.$type = 'EmployeeViewModel ';
};

var mapping = {
    'employees': {
        create: function (options) {
            return new EmployeeViewModel(options.data);
        }
    },
    'adSearchResults': {
        create: function (options) {
            return new AdSearchResultsViewModel(options.data);
        }
    }
};
```

And this the EmployeeSearch ajax function:

```
$("#EmployeeSearch").autocomplete({

        source: function (request, response) {
            $("#ajaxLoading").show(),

            $.ajax({
                url: "https://somesite.com/adsearch/search/directory",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    User: request.term,
                    Scope: "All"
                },

                success: function (data) {
                    viewModel.adSearchResults.removeAll();
                    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, viewModel.adSearchResults);
                    viewModel.adSearchResults.remove(function (item) { return item.Email() == ""; });
                    $("#ajaxLoading").hide();
                }
            });
        },
```

However, when I start typing a name into the textbox to search for the user, if I search for *John.Doe*, the search will return the correct results. Also if I type in *John*, it will return the correct results. But if I type in *John Doe*, it stops returning the correct results. So to me, it seems that the search is bound to the UserName property. How can I bind it to the FullName property? This is what I have now, and I'm not sure how it's even bound to the UserName property to begin with.

```
<input id="EmployeeSearch" class="ui-icon-search" /><br />
        <div>
            <div class="DualListBox">
                <div style="float: left; width: 400px;">
                    <label>Search Results:</label>
                    <img id="ajaxLoading" src="~/Content/Images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif" style="display: none;" />
                    <select style="height: 335px; width: 400px;" multiple="multiple" data-bind="options: adSearchResults, selectedOptions: availableSelectedMembers, optionsText: function (item) { return item.FullName() + ', ' + item.Email() }"></select>
                </div>
```

Comment: It looks like you are using: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/
Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it's jquery with knockout js.

Comment: You should try to throw a `console.log(data)` inside the ajax success function in order to see what is returned. The call to `ko.mapping.fromJS` is what is setting the values for your view model so whatever data you pass to it and how you are mapping things is handled by you. Try debugging more and you should be able to find the point of failure.

Comment: I've already seen what is returned. "The data object is an array of objects that have properties such as UserName and FullName. So if data[0].UserName is 'John.Doe' then data[0].FullName would be 'John Doe'. When debugging, I can see that the data object has all of the correct values." And you can see I'm passing the data object into ko.mapping.js. I just don't know how to get it to work on the front end. The front end thinks it's bound to UserName.